# change the "Cancel" text on SaveAs Dialog box in excel VBA to "Review"

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to change the "Cancel" text on SaveAs Dialog box in excel VBA to "Review"?

I have no idea how to change the default Yes, No, Cancel setting.

Will appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

To do this you would need to:

1. Intercept the SaveAs with a `Workbook` Event
2. Exit if the user was using `Save` rather than `SaveAs`
3. Provided your own customised `SaveAs` UserForm (`UserForm1.Show` below as a sample line to an un-designed form)

Note that `Events` should be disabled to prevent your UserForm Save from re-calling the `Workbook_BeforeSave` Event

All up - I'd stay with the defaults!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'exit on Save
If Not SaveAsUI Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cancel = True
UserForm1.Show
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `All up - I'd stay with the defaults!` Me too!